# How to create a solution wide DataSet.xsd

Tags: c#, reporting-services, xsd, dataset

I have a solution in VS 2013 with 3 projects inside.

- Main (EXE)
- Classes (DLL)
- Reports (DLL with embedded RDLC files)

Now I have `DataSet.xsd` file stored inside a folder (\DataSources) in the Main project. I need to access `DataSet.xsd` also from Reports project because I'm using the Report Wizard Tool to configure reports.

When I add a new report on the Reports project I'm asked to create a new DataSet and also a new ConnectionString.

I don't want this since there's already the ConnectionString and DataSet.xsd in the main project.

How can I make the XSD solution wide?